# JmsOutboundGateway : Manual Start and Stop

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-jms

We have an application with around 75 partitioned steps spread around 100 jobs. Our configuration for the outbound gateway is:

```
<int-jms:outbound-gateway 
    id="outbound-gateway_1"
    auto-startup="true" 
    connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
    request-channel="jms.requests_1"
    request-destination="jms.requestsQueue"
    reply-channel="jms.reply_1"
    reply-destination="jms.repliesQueue"
    receive-timeout="${timeout}"
    correlation-key="JMSCorrelationID" >
    <int-jms:reply-listener receive-timeout="1000"/>
</int-jms:outbound-gateway>
```

When autostart="true" we see the replyListener thread for each outbound gateway. To remove this extra load and resource consumption, we change to autostart="false" and added a step listener for the partitioned step the start and stop the gateway in the beforeStep and afterStep methods. At server startup the replyListener threads are not there as expected. They appear during step execution but are not removed after the call to stop on the outbound gateway (even after waiting a prolonged period).

Is something else needed to cleanup the replyListener?

Comment: How do you know that those threads are still there? And which version of Spring Integration do you use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see what you mean. That looks like:

```
while ((active = isActive()) && !isRunning()) {
    if (interrupted) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Thread was interrupted while waiting for " +
                "a restart of the listener container, but container is still stopped");
    }
    if (!wasWaiting) {
            decreaseActiveInvokerCount();
    }
    wasWaiting = true;
    try {
        lifecycleMonitor.wait();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // Re-interrupt current thread, to allow other threads to react.
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        interrupted = true;
    }
}
```

in the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer.AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop()`

The point there is `lifecycleMonitor.wait();` and pay attention to the message of the `IllegalStateException`.

Not sure what is the purpose of such a design, but we dontt have choice unless live with that as is.

Further the logic in the `start()` is based on the `this.pausedTasks` local cache, which is filled during `doInitialize()` if container `!this.running`.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR), if you think that logic must be changed somehow.

Comment: All of our partitions partition jobs listen to the same JMS queue and use different channels. Is there a way to configure the outbound gateways to use the same replyListener instance and they only 1 would need to be running (getting rid of start and stopping?

Comment: Consider do not use `<int-jms:reply-listener>` for your use-case. I even not sure that you need static `reply-destination` for your dynamic sample. A `TemporaryQueue` solution should be enough.

Comment: Use an external task executor that prefers short lived tasks, or explicitly set `max-messages-per-task` (which is set to 10 with that type of executor). When max messages per task is > 0, the thread will terminate (or put back in the pool) instead of blocking on that monitor.